# How to Search and find Word ( No sensitivity to upper or lower character )

Tags: c#, search, character, uppercase, lowercase

I write a code :

```
string strSearch = textBox1.Text;
XDocument xdoc;
List<string> lstItemsForAdd;
lstItemsForAdd = xdoc.Descendants("name")
                        .Where(item => item.Value.Contains(strSearch))
                        .Select(item => item.Value)
                        .Take(5)
                        .OrderBy(item => item)
                        .ToList();
```

Now this code is sensitivity to upper and lower character for find ......
How can I do for search without sensitivity to upper and lower character
but i don't want convert items and strSearch to lower/upper character
 
so how can I do ?

Thanks and kind regards.

Comment: check StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase

Comment: `@Mate` i try for use from `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` but in this code can't use ! can i use ? how ?

Comment: I have added an answer with an example. I hope it will be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
string strSearch = textBox1.Text;
XDocument xdoc;
List<string> lstItemsForAdd;
lstItemsForAdd = xdoc.Descendants("name")
                        .Where(item => item.Value.IndexOf(strSearch. StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
                        .Select(item => item.Value)
                        .Take(5)
                        .OrderBy(item => item)
                        .ToList();
```